# function in vim to fix quotations

Tags: function, vim, quotes

I'm trying to create a function in vim to be activated by a shortcut and go through my document and re-quote the strings using Python-like syntax. That is:

- `"something"` -> `'something'`
- `'''docstring'''` -> `"""docstring"""`
- `"'"` -> `"'"` (stays the same)
- `'"'` -> `'"'` (stays the same)

Given my limited knowledge of python functions I came up with this in my `.vimrc`:

```
function! Fixquotes()
   :silent! %s/"\([^"]*\)"/'\1'/g
   :silent! %s/'""/"""/
   :silent! %s/""'/"""/
   :silent! %s/'''/"""/g
endfunction

inoremap <C-f> <esc>mk:call Fixquotes()<CR>`kli
noremap <C-f> mk:call Fixquotes()<CR>`k
```

It kinda work, except for the case where I have `"'"` since the first substitution will turn it into `'''` and the last will turn it into `"""`.

Does anyone have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
function! Fixquotes()
   :silent! %s/\v([^'"]|\_^)\zs"([^"']*)"\ze([^'"]|\_$)/'\2'/g
   :silent! %s/'''/"""/g
endfunction
```